# Como voltar para uma activity já criada sem recriá-la novamente?

Tags: android

Eu sei que que as activities no Android ficam armazenadas como uma pilha. Mas eu precisava usar o botão `onBackPressed()` e voltar há 2 telas atrás sem recriar essa tela. Com o intent ele recria a tela. É possível voltar 2 telas atrás sem recriar a activity? Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar as constantes que a classe `Intent` oferece para os desenvolvedores.

Exemplo:

```
Intent it = new Intent(Class1.this, Class2.class);
it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(it);
```

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY:

> If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack.

Português:

> Se definido, a nova Activity não é mantida no histórico de pilhas.

Documentação e outras constantes:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#constants

Comment: obrigado vou olhar isso.